# How can we obtain a userspace file descriptor from the kernel's struct file (and vice versa)?

Tags: c, file, linux-kernel

I need to open a file as a `struct file` in kernel space and return the file's `int` descriptor to the userspace, and I also need to pass an `int` descriptor to the kernel space and be able to retrieve the corresponding kernel `struct file`.

How do I do that? I open the files in the kernel with `filp_open`.

Comment: see the exported symbols `fd_install()` and `fget_raw()`; do those help?

Comment: The issue with many of these API is that they're not really much documented. From what I could gather, I guess `fd_install()` creates a descriptor on the `int` value we pass (which could be problematic as I don't really know what values are free to use) from the `struct file`. What do I need to call to undo it when I release the resources, before doing `filp_close()`? And I read on the function `__fd_install()` (called by `fd_install`) that some weird race condition can happen there: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.7/source/fs/file.c#L590 Do I need to handle it if I only call `fd_install`?

Comment: And what does `fget_raw` do exactly? From reading its source it looks like it returns the associated `struct_file` to a descriptor. If that's the case it should really help

Comment: And quite importantly, when the file descriptor is obtained from the `struct file` or viceversa, does one keep the information of how far the other went into reading/writing? Like, if I get a descriptor from user space, and the user had read up to byte X, if I do `fget_raw`, obtain the struct file and then read with `kernel_read` from it, will I start reading from byte X or from the beginning?